# Expandable Search Form (CSS)

Tags: jquery, search, expand

I am having a dilemma here with an expandable search forms. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/pDVvK/ and below is the css part that triggers the expand

```
    input[type=search] {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 10px 60px 10px 32px;
    width: 55px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #eae9e9;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
input[type=search]:focus {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #6dcff6;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}
```

As you can see, on focus it expands to the right [till the set width] but what i am trying to achieve is the same effect but with an expansion to the left. I have tried achieving that with paddings alone but i couldn't do it.

Any idea on how to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Here is rough edit
http://jsfiddle.net/tousif123/pDVvK/2/

Just enclose the searchbox in a div and make the searchbox float right

```
input[type=search] {
float:right;
}
```

**Here is the whole code:-**

```css
.form-holder {
 float: right; 
}

/* reset webkit search input browser style */
input {
 outline: none;
}
input[type=search] {
 -webkit-appearance: textfield;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
 font-family: inherit;
 
}
input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
 display: none; /* remove the search and cancel icon */
}

/* search input field */
input[type=search] {
    float:right;
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
 padding: 10px 60px 10px 32px;
 width: 55px;
 
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #eae9e9;
 
 -webkit-transition: all .5s;
 -moz-transition: all .5s;
 transition: all .5s;
    
}
input[type=search]:focus {
 width: 100px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: #6dcff6;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109,207,246,.5);
}

/* placeholder */
input:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #999;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #999;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.form_wrap
{
    width:250px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="form_wrap">    
<form>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
 </div>
```